# How to use Vue with Lumen?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, lumen

I have created a RESTful API with lumen and tested it with postman. It works fine. Now I wanna develop the front end for it with Vue. What is the best way to go about it? Do I need to create a separate directory for Vue or is there a way to use it in the same lumen project directory? I have tried installing `composer require laravel/ui` which works fine. But then when I run `php artisan ui vue` it says "ui not defined". Help me out here.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use something like this [starter kit](https://github.com/gentritabazi01/Vue-Lumen-Starter). Down the line it will save your time.